# The given key was not present in the dictionary (following fb canvas page tutorial)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, facebook

I'm following the tutorial at http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/aspnet-mvc-facebook-birthday-app exactly but when I run the project, it is giving me an error that says the given key was not present in the dictionary. Any ideas on how this is happening when I have done next to nothing in the project so far?

Here is the stack trace:

```
[KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary.]
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key) +11165993
Microsoft.AspNet.Facebook.PermissionsStatus.ConvertApiResult(IList`1 apiResults) +189
Microsoft.AspNet.Facebook.PermissionsStatus..ctor(IList`1 apiResult) +68

Microsoft.AspNet.Facebook.Providers.DefaultFacebookPermissionService.GetUserPermissionsStatus(String userId, String accessToken) +261
Microsoft.AspNet.Facebook.Authorization.FacebookAuthorizeFilter.OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext) +5655
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAuthorizationFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor) +143
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__19(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState) +1680
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState) +59
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +151
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, BeginInvokeDelegate beginDelegate, EndInvokeDelegate`1 endDelegate, Object tag, Int32 timeout) +94
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.BeginInvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +559
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1c(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +82
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState) +73
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +151
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState, BeginInvokeDelegate`1 beginDelegate, EndInvokeVoidDelegate`1 endDelegate, TState invokeState, Object tag, Int32 timeout, SynchronizationContext callbackSyncContext) +105
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecuteCore(AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +588
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__14(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object callbackState, Controller controller) +47
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState) +65
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +151
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState, BeginInvokeDelegate`1 beginDelegate, EndInvokeVoidDelegate`1 endDelegate, TState invokeState, Object tag, Int32 timeout, SynchronizationContext callbackSyncContext) +139
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +484
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +50
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__4(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState, ProcessRequestState innerState) +98
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState) +73
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +151
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState, BeginInvokeDelegate`1 beginDelegate, EndInvokeVoidDelegate`1 endDelegate, TState invokeState, Object tag, Int32 timeout, SynchronizationContext callbackSyncContext) +106
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +446
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +88
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +50
System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +834
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +188

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.34009
```

Comment: Hi Just a gentle suggestion. Try to keep your results / log formatted, e.g. here I put your outcome to a text area. In general, try to follow [these rules](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Your original text was really painful to read.

Comment: Thank you. I put it in the code format because I thought that was what you are supposed to use for stack traces.

Comment: Stack Overflow is different about that, you indent four spaces to create an a <pre> or <code> block.

Comment: Got the exact same problem, have you find any solutions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was an issue in the Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Facebook library. I patched the lib and send the fix to the AspNetMvcStack team for review/integration. Everything is explained in the ticket :)

Ticket : https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/2241